# c# basic formatting question

Tags: c#, string, variables, formatting

If I wanted to swap out part of a statement with a variable i.e.

tempCube.transform.parent = row(var would need to go here ie an int that is iterated with a for loop).transform;

How would I write this. Sorry for the really basic question, I have been using other languages too long and now I have gone back to c# I have almost forgotten everything I had learned.

"*(i)*" is the bit I want to swap out with a variable

eg

> for(int i = 1; i <= 3; i++){ print row*(i)*.transform; }

Console:

(1,2,3)
(2,3,4)
(4,5,6)

Comment: Please do an example of an input and output state!

Comment: What does Transform do, and what does it return?

Comment: It doesnt really matter, but it returns a vector 3 which is struct comprised of 3 floats (x,y,z)

Comment: If you are having trouble explaining your question, you could post example code in any language and ask for the C# equivalent.

Comment: @SacredGeometry please don't deface your posts like this, it has an accepted answer so you can't delete it. I have rolled it back to the previous version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like:-

```
row1.transform;
row2.transform;
row3.transform;
...
```

If so, no, you can't replace that text at runtime. You should use a collection. Ideally make an IEnumerable out of them and use foreach:-

```
foreach (var x in new { row1, row2, row3 ... })
{
  x.transform;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean, i hope you want to specify the index, is this what you are looking for (index is the int you mentioned)

```
tempCube.transform.parent = row[index].transform;
```

Comment: I dont thinks thats it, I dont want to specify an index of an array. What i want to do is swap out the text at compile time with a variable that returns a integer.

Comment: Can you edit the question with an example ? which is the string and what is to be replaced difficult to visualize as of now